# Prime ideals in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ above rational prime ideals

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm really struggling to understand the concept of prime ideals lying above and below a given prime ideal. For example taking the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})\big/\mathbb{Q}$, how do we know $(2, 1+ \sqrt{-5})$ the **only** ideal in the bigger field lying above $(2)$? And why do $(3, 1+\sqrt{-5})$ and $(3, 1-\sqrt{-5})$ lie above $(3)$? (Sorry I appreciate that this is probably very elementary but I'm new to algebraic number theory and all the books I have just skip over this point assuming it is obvious to the reader which sadly it's not...)

Comment: This  ring is a field so there are only two ideals! You might want to talk about ideal in $\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.

Comment: It is sometimes a standard abuse of language to talk about "units in $K$" or "ideals of $K$", and really talk about its ring of integers.

Comment: Well, one can indeed readily verify those two particular assertions. However, in general, the question how many and which prime ideals of a ring of integers are lying above a given prime number is _not_ elementary. Indeed, a large part of algebraic number theory is devoted to find partial answers to just this question.

Comment: yes, sorry i was referring to the ring of integers! and i realise it's not elementary in general, just in the given example. And I'm not sure how i would have approached the question without being given the ideals to verify/how to know these are the only examples. thanks for your help so far!

Comment: For your specific case, $(2)(3)$ = $(1 + \sqrt{-5})(1 - \sqrt{-5})$ as ideals. All the terms are irreducible (look at the norm). Then the idea is that if $\pi$ an ideal, $\pi|(6)$ then $\pi|(2)$ and $(1+\sqrt{-5})$ (or (3) and $(1+\sqrt{-5})$ or any of the 4 combinations you can make). 

In the $\pi|(2)$ and $(1+\sqrt{-5})$ case, we get $\pi | (2) + (1+\sqrt{-5}) = (2,1+\sqrt{-5})$. Then you can use dimension arguments to show that at most 2 ideals lie above (2) and verify our guess. Note that this is a sort-of heuristic but can be made rigorous.

Comment: nice 'nym ${}{}$

Comment: I think that in their mania to use the words "over" and "above", a lot of writers on ANT obscure the concept of containment. For example, $\langle 4 \rangle$ is contained within $\langle 2 \rangle$. Both of these are ideals, and $\langle 2 \rangle$ is a prime ideal in some contexts, like $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ (which you'll probably study at some point in the future, if you haven't already).

Answer (score 8):

To see how this works, it's most simple to appeal to the norm and the concept of "ramification." The most likely reason this was glossed over in your text is that you probably haven't proven these theorems yet, and I agree it's not immediately obvious why it's true otherwise.

So first let me start with the statement of Dedekind's Discriminant Theorem

> Let $K/\Bbb Q$ be a finite field extension with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$. Then the ideal $p\mathcal{O}_k$ is [ramified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramification#In_algebraic_number_theory) iff $p|\Delta_K$, the discriminant of $K$.

Then since we know for quadratic fields, $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{m})$ with $m$ square-free that

> $$\Delta_K=\begin{cases} m & m\equiv 1\mod 4 \\ 4m & m\equiv 2,3\mod 4\end{cases}.$$

Now, $-5\equiv 3\mod 4$ so that with $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-5})$ we have $\Delta_K=-20$. Then we know that when we factor $(2)$ into prime ideals we have

> $$(2)=\mathfrak{p}_1^{e_1}\ldots\mathfrak{p}_r^{e_r}$$

with some $e_i>1$. Since $N((2))=N(2)=4$ we see that $N(\mathfrak{p}_i)|4$, i.e. $N(\mathfrak{p}_i)\in\{2,4\}$. Assume WLOG $e_1>1$. Then $N(\mathfrak{p}_1^{e_1})>N(\mathfrak{p}_1)^2\ge 4$. So it must be that $e_1=2$ and $N(\mathfrak{p}_1)=2$, since any larger and the norm of the product is bigger than $4$, which is impossible. But then if we have some other prime $\mathfrak{p}_2$ in that factorization, i.e. $r>1$ then $N(\mathfrak{p}_2)\ge 2$ so that the norm of the product is at least $8$, impossible. So we conclude there is but one prime above $2$.

Now how do we conclude based on similar information that there are two primes (and no more) above $3$? Well, first we'd like to know that the ideals are actually above $3$.

> In number theory if we have two integer rings $\mathcal{O}_K\subseteq\mathcal{O}_L$ the phrase "$\mathfrak{P}$ lies above $\mathfrak{p}$" means that $\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_L=\mathfrak{P}^{e}\cdot\mathfrak{a}$ for some ideal $\mathfrak{a}\subseteq\mathcal{O}_L$. That is:  $\mathfrak{P}$ appears in the prime factorization of the ideal $\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_L\subseteq\mathcal{O}_L$.

In your case we can see that both of the given primes are indeed "above" $3$, so it suffices to see that there can be no more. Again, noting

> $$(3,1+\sqrt{-5})(3,1-\sqrt{-5})|(3)$$

We see that $N((3,1\pm\sqrt{-5}))|N(3)=9$. But then if there are more primes in the factorization of $(3)$ we would get too big of a norm again, so there are at most $2$ primes above $3$, hence exactly $2$.

The same logic goes through other ideals, you can see the same construction works for all primes since their norms are squares, so there are always at most $2$ in a quadratic extension. Proving there are $2$ usually amounts to providing $2$ distinct ideals, proving there is only $1$ in the ramified case (i.e. primes dividing the discriminant) is exactly the same, and then for the others for which there is only one prime, but it is not ramified, things can get a bit trickier, and is usually more ad-hoc (unless you know a suitably advanced form of quadratic reciprocity).

Comment: thank you, that's really useful :)

Comment: @anon is there something else you're looking for that could be added to my response? You didn't accept an answer yet, so I assume you're still unclear on something.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $K$ is a number field, by definition, this means that $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, and WLOG we can even assume that $K\subset \mathbb{C}$ with the condition that $[K:\mathbb{Q}]<\infty$.

Associated to any number field $K$, are the generalization of integers, called the *ring of integers* of $K$, these are the elements $x\in K$, so that $x$ satisfies a monic polynomial with **integer** coefficients. We denote the set of all such integral elements by $\mathcal{O}_K$. One can show that $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a sub-ring of $K$.

In algebraic number theory, one usually works with prime ideals, instead of prime elements (because the ring of integers usually does not have unique factorization). The prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ are of the form $p\mathbb{Z}$ where $p$ is a prime number. We say that a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subset \mathcal{O}_K$, *lies above*, or, *divides* $p$, if $\mathfrak{p}\cap \mathbb{Z} = p\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you know that given a ring $R$ and an ideal $\mathfrak a$ there is a 1-1 correspondence between ideals containing $\mathfrak a$ (i.e. ideals *above* $\mathfrak a$) and ideals of $R/\mathfrak a$. Taking your ring of integers and a prime number $p$, the quotient is a quadratic (in your case) extension of a finite field. A polynomial ring over a field is a PID, so it is the quotient either by an irreducible polynomial, or by a polynomial that splits in two factors, usually different but occasionally equal, as in your case above 2. The prime ideals are generated by $p$ with the representative of a generator of a maximal ideal in these quotients.